# update multi row php

Tags: php, mysql

i try to update a multi row like this

```html
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$size = count($_POST['compo']);

while ($i < $size) {

    $compo = $_POST['compo'][$i];
    $fill = $_POST['fill'][$i];
    $query = "UPDATE Invantsion Set compon='".$compo."',Num='".$fill."' where ID='".$ID."'";
    ++$i;
}
```

the code on post is bulit from to parts..

```html
<tr>
    <td align="center"><span lang="he"><font size="2" face="Arial">
 <?php
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='compo[$i]' value='".$row['compon']."'>".$row['compon']."";
 ?>
 </font></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name='fill[$i]' style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold">
    <?php
        $Uid = $row['id'];
        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/com.php' );
     echo "</select>";
    }
    ?>
```

who getting the new data for mysql and the sec part who get the original data for MYSQL

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='".$row['ID']."'>"; 
?>
 <tr>
  <td align="center"><span lang="he"><font size="2" face="Arial">
  <?php
  echo $row['compon'];
  ?>
  </font></span>
        </td>
  <td align="center"><span lang="he"><font size="2" face="Arial">
  <?php
  echo $row['Num'];
  ?>
  </font></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

what should be worng if i get error 500 or just the last result 
UPDATE Invantsion Set compon='DECODERS',Num='' where ID='30'
and if i try to make the code looping only the words after set it no doing nothing at all..
any one?

Comment: check your (error) logs

Comment: there no logs..